# Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible from Rails 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my app is broken after the update of Rails fom 5.1 to 5.2

The error is: `Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible, Incompatible values: [:create_with]):` and I cannot understand what is wrong.

The issue come from this scope

```
  scope :publication, -> do
    where.not(type: 'Content::Teaser').
      where.not(home_position: nil).
      or(
        Content::Teaser.where(
          id: Content::Teaser.select(:id).joins(:content).where(content: Content.publication)
        )
      )
  end
```

Why this error?

Comment: Try using `Content::Teaser.joins......pluck(:id)` instead of `select(:id)`.

Comment: I try with `Content::Teaser.joins(:content).where(content: Content.publication).pluck(:id)` but i receive the same error

Comment: You don't have to explicitly select ids for subquerys. You should be able to do: `or(Content::Teaser.joins(:content).where(Content.publication))`. Don't listen to people that tell you to use `.pluck` - its widely missused and in many sitautions will create performance problems since it will force a query and load the data into ruby instead of creating a subquery.  `.pluck` should only be used when you actually want an array of data in Ruby - not to construct queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
# scope should only really be used for one-liners as its just syntactic sugar 
# and hurts the readability of your code
def self.publication
  where.not(type: 'Content::Teaser').
    where.not(home_position: nil).or(
      # provided that Content.publication is a scope
      Content::Teaser.joins(:content).where(Content.publication) 
    )
  )
end
```

Comment: `ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins, :create_with]`

Content.publication is not a scope, is a status of the Content model (enum)